# Scrape Verify link Href From Sites

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, discord

I want to get the Verify href from [GmailnatorInbox](https://www.gmailnator.com/geralddoreyestmp/messageid/#179b454b4c482c4d) and this site contains the href discord verify which is the following [Discord Verify HREF](https://click.discord.com/ls/click?upn=qDOo8cnwIoKzt0aLL1cBeFE1RlVCKJFF5zAq8ml-2BFh1dq-2FeX22E9yMPFmLMSO5CYblhLhvyRB3ayzmbxFRrAlMAZ55FnzLLYTe9bxB-2F2hBMoJx4ENWveEKol2WvJImLHCxCPx0QwpGR4JD2sRmfx-2BrDLejesUAQtDcVtsfABQNKLw8G5L7Vu1UmlU8b982qpbZrlmrakoQYNgE-2BaxhdvXnDYn-2FDOMxMwMiV2jK9mbZs-3DsP0h_3Tswyie9C2vHlXKXm6tJrQwhGg-2FvQ76GD2o0Zl2plCYHULNsKdCuB6s-2BHk1oNirSuR8goxCccVgwsQHdq1YYeDIcn-2Fh0rQk-2BSFY9LhtklWf7DPC8q5YarD1CygqBHCn-2Bo-2BQUWMRDOu0QvpgbQRy7rYpkPejJHcLtM-2B4Gt-2BfGi6UzqaUXiK8xc6dS4F1uZHXBW2XSKXMtL1iElfVPeHErpJjFss-2FoSn68fTEI9zmE3QQ-3D)

I want to get this href using bs4 and pass it into a selenium driver link like `driver.get(url)` the `url` being the href ofc.

Can someone make some code to scrape the href from the gmailnator inbox please? I did try the page source however the page source does not contain the href.

This is the code I have written to get the href but the href that I require (discord one) is in a frame source so I think that's why it doesnt come up.

**UPDATE! EVERYTHING IS DONE AND FIXED**

```
driver.get('https://www.gmailnator.com/inbox/#for.ev.e.r.my.girlt.m.p@gmail.com')
time.sleep(6)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mailList"]/tbody/tr[2]/td/a/table/tbody/tr/td[1]').click()
time.sleep(4)
url = driver.current_url
email_for_data = driver.current_url.split('/')[-3]
print(url)
time.sleep(2)
print('Getting Your Discord Verify link')
print('Time To Get Your Discord Link')
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "lxml")
data_email = soup.find("")
token = soup.find("meta", {"name": "csrf-token"})["content"]
cf_email = soup.find("a", class_="__cf_email__")["data-cfemail"]

endpoint = "https://www.gmailnator.com/mailbox/get_single_message/"

data = {
    "csrf_gmailnator_token": token,
    "action": "get_message",
    "message_id": url.split("#")[-1],
    "email": f"{email_for_data}",
}

headers = {
    "referer": f"https://www.gmailnator.com/{email_for_data}/messageid/",
    "cookie": f"csrf_gmailnator_cookie={token}; ci_session={cf_email}",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) "
                  "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.86 "
                  "YaBrowser/21.3.0.740 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36",
    "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest",
}

r = requests.post(endpoint, data=data, headers=headers)
the_real_slim_shady = (
    BeautifulSoup(r.json()["content"], "lxml")
    .find_all("a", {"target": "_blank"})[1]["href"]
)
print(the_real_slim_shady)
```

Comment: Can we at least see your effort for the problem ? SO is not a platform where we write the code for you. We are just here to help you out, please keep this in mind.

Comment: sure ill provide it up i also found out some other info that the href that is required is within a iframe srcdoc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fake it all with pure `requests` to get the `Verify` link. First, you need to get the `token` and the `cf_email` values. Then, things are pretty straightforward.

Here's how to get the link:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.gmailnator.com/geralddoreyestmp/messageid/#179b454b4c482c4d"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "lxml")

token = soup.find("meta", {"name": "csrf-token"})["content"]
cf_email = soup.find("a", class_="__cf_email__")["data-cfemail"]

endpoint = "https://www.gmailnator.com/mailbox/get_single_message/"

data = {
    "csrf_gmailnator_token": token,
    "action": "get_message",
    "message_id": url.split("#")[-1],
    "email": "geralddoreyestmp",
}

headers = {
    "referer": "https://www.gmailnator.com/geralddoreyestmp/messageid/",
    "cookie": f"csrf_gmailnator_cookie={token}; ci_session={cf_email}",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) "
                  "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.86 "
                  "YaBrowser/21.3.0.740 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36",
    "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest",
}

r = requests.post(endpoint, data=data, headers=headers)
the_real_slim_shady = (
    BeautifulSoup(r.json()["content"], "lxml")
    .find_all("a", {"target": "_blank"})[1]["href"]
)
print(the_real_slim_shady)
```

Output (your link will be different!):

```
https://click.discord.com/ls/click?upn=qDOo8cnwIoKzt0aLL1cBeARJoBrGSa2vu41A5vK-2B4us-3D77CR_3Tswyie9C2vHlXKXm6tJrQwhGg-2FvQ76GD2o0Zl2plCYHULNsKdCuB6s-2BHk1oNirSuR8goxCccVgwsQHdq1YYeGQki4wtPdDA3zi661IJL7H0cOYMH0IJ0t3sgrvr2oMX-2BJBA-2BWZzY42AwgjdQ-2BMAN9Y5ctocPNK-2FUQLxf6HQusMayIeATMiTO-2BlpDytu-2FnIW4axB32RYQpxPGO-2BeHtcSj7a7QeZmqK-2B-2FYkKA4dl5q8I-3D
```

Comment: for some reason this was working just a while ago but isnt as of now. the error i get ```Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)``` ill update my code so u can see how im doing it. when im doing it with ur code it seems to work fine.

Comment: And what exactly you're trying to do?

Comment: i get the message id link using seleniums driver.current.url. ive updated my code above it does not seems to work for some reason.

Comment: wait i think ik what the issue is. the headers referer and the data email. but i cant seem to get around on how to make the email in data and referer in {} format so that it gets it from the current url

Comment: never mind i have gotten it. i used splits i will edit my code to the fixed one.

Comment: i just relieased the code that u used gets the image href not the verify button href could u please edit ur code to make it so it gets the verify button href please.

Comment: please change the href [0] into [1] to get the verify href link. i have fixed it